# Segmentation fault in c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
#include<iostream>   
using namespace std; 

class Toto{  
private:  
   int w;   
public:  
    Toto();     //constructor   
    int *veg;     //pointer veg  
        void  func9()   
    {   
         veg =new int [4] ; //dynamic mem allocation     
    }   
        void func7()   
    {   
        delete [] veg;  //free mem    
    }      
};                                                                  

Toto::Toto() 
{   
    cout <<" contructor is here: " << endl;   
} 

int main () 
{ 

Toto pen;
cout << "enter numbers: ";  
for (int i=0;i<4;i++) 
{ 
    cin >> pen.veg[i];  
}
cout << endl;  
for (int i=0;i<4;i++) 
{ 
    cout << pen.veg[i] << " " << endl;  
}

return 0;
}
```

The code above produces a Seg Fault for some reason. 
After numbers are typed this code produces seg fault!
Please forgive the messy code, just a beginner thank you in advance!

Comment: `veg` has no storage allocated - you would need to call the `func9()` method first to allocate some.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use `int veg[4]` in `Toto`?

Answer (score 0):

`veg` is only set to a valid value if you call `func9()` *before* attempting to use it. If you were to do that, you could play around with `veg[0]` through `veg[3]` to your heart's content, provided you didn't call `func7()` to release the memory.

Allocation of required member variables is something that should generally be done in a constructor (and deallocation in a destructor), avoiding these sorts of problems.

One of the major advantages of constructors is to ensure variable are properly and *fully* initialised before any use of the object takes part.

*One* way to do this is by modifying your code thus:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Toto{
    private:
        int w;
    public:
        int *veg;
        Toto() { veg = new int[4]; }
        ~Toto() { delete[] veg; }
};

int main (void) {
    Toto pen;

    cout << "enter numbers: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        cin >> pen.veg[i];
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        cout << pen.veg[i] << " " << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Then you don't have to worry at all whether you've called member functions before trying to use the components of the object.

Comment: @Algo, I see you've unaccepted my answer so I have to assume you've discovered some reason why it's no longer the best answer. Perhaps, if you could share that reason, I'd be happy to either fix it or explain further.

Answer (score 0):

`veg` isn't allocated. Best approach to allocate it in constructor and delete in destructor, like this:

```
class Toto{  
private:  
   int w;   
public:  
    int *veg;     //pointer veg 
    Toto() {
        veg =new int [4] ; //dynamic mem allocation
    };     //constructor   


    ~Toto() {   
        delete [] veg;  //free mem    
    };      
};
```

Or you should call `func9()` before using  `veg`

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on dynamic allocation, do it like this:

```
class Toto {  
private:  
   int w;   
public:  
    Toto();     //constructor   
    ~Toto();    //destructor
    int * veg;     //pointer veg  
};

Toto::Toto() : veg(new int[4])
{   
    cout <<" contructor is here: " << endl;   
}

Toto::~Toto() {
    delete[] veg;
}
```